# setting state with onChange in React results in canvas being null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I have a simple application consisting of two - parent App and child Circle components. My aim is to draw circle on canvas (Circle component does that) and have input that takes number value and makes angle of that numerical value with the radius. like so :
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUNjp.png)

**The problem is**, i've set up onChange event listener with handler on input, which is supposed to update my state, but whenever i type something into input field, it tells me that my canvas is null, and .getContext("2d") method can't be performed, which messes up entire application. 
I've googled and found out that this is because of the fact that canvas renders **after** state is updated, or something like that. I can't think of any solution that would make that possible. here's my code :

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { degreesToRadiansFlipped } from "./helpers/helpers";
import Circle from "./components/Circle";
class App extends Component {
  state = { degrees: 0 };
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ degrees: event.target.value });
  };

  coordinates = {
    x: Math.cos(degreesToRadiansFlipped(120)) * 100 + 150,
    y: Math.sin(degreesToRadiansFlipped(120)) * 100 + 150
  };
  drawCircle = (context, x, y) => {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(150, 150, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.moveTo(150, 150);
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.stroke();
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.currentDegreeValue);
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <Circle drawCircle={this.drawCircle} coordinates={this.coordinates} />
        <form>
          <input name="degrees" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Circle.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Circle extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.drawCircle(
      this.context,
      this.props.coordinates.x,
      this.props.coordinates.y
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <canvas
        ref={(canvas) => (this.context = canvas.getContext("2d"))}
        width={300}
        height={300}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Circle;
```

**Actual Error is :**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Comment: have you tried `ref={(canvas) => (this.context = canvas!.getContext("2d"))}`?

Answer (score 0):

// index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Circle from "./Circle";

class App extends Component {
  state = { degrees: 0, showCirle: false };
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ degrees: event.target.value, showCirle: true });
  };
  degreesToRadiansFlipped(angle) {
    return (angle + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI);
  }
  coordinates = {
    x: Math.cos(this.degreesToRadiansFlipped(120)) * 100 + 150,
    y: Math.sin(this.degreesToRadiansFlipped(120)) * 100 + 150
  };
  drawCircle = (context, x, y) => {
    console.log("inside drawcircle");
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(150, 150, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.moveTo(150, 150);
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.stroke();
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.currentDegreeValue);
    return (
      <div className="main">
        {this.state.showCirle && (
          <Circle drawCircle={this.drawCircle} coordinates={this.coordinates} />
        )}
        <form>
          <input name="degrees" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

// Circel Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Circle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  fillContext = () => {
    const canvas = this.refs.canvas
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    this.context = ctx
    this.props.drawCircle(
      this.context,
      this.props.coordinates.x,
      this.props.coordinates.y
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fillContext()
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.fillContext()
  }
  render() {
    return <canvas ref="canvas" width={300} height={300} />;
  }
}

export default Circle;
```

In your example, x and y coordinates should change based on input value change, but coordinates is an object with fixed x and y values. I think that logic should also change.